# bash input/ouput to a log file

Tags: linux, bash, logging

I have a bash script with below statement. I need to output both the question "Are you happy? and the answer "yes" or "no" to a log file. I'm able to get the answer to log file with "echo "$yn" >>log1.log 2>&1" but not the question (read command)

```
while true; do
    read -p "Are you happy? " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
echo "$yn" >>log1.log 2>&1
```

What I have tried:
read -p "Are you okay?" yn > log.log 2>&1
This will indeed work, however when I run my scrip the question is not displayed.
The only way I found is to echo "Are you happy? $yn" >>log1.log 2>&1
The problem with this is that I have several prompts with long statements, I like to keep my scripts nice and short

Comment: Something like this `read -p '...' yn 2>&1 | tee logfile`?

Comment: @randomir nope, does not recognize my input. I run the script, hit "yes" then its asking me "Please answer yes or no."

Comment: Have you added `| tee ..`?

Comment: yes.  yn 2>&1 | tee log.log

Comment: Perhaps `echo "Are you happy? ${yn}" >> log1.log`?

Comment: @twalberg that is my plan if I cant come up with something easier :)

Comment: @tripleee you got it to work with read -p "Are you okay?" yn > log.log 2>&1 ?

Comment: No, I didn't catch the precise requirements before. Posted an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

The redirect only applies to the `echo`. You need to add a similar redirect afther the `done`. (This will also redirect the error message which you `echo` from within `case`, which incidentally should go to standard error):

```
while true; do
    read -p "Are you happy? " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no." >&2;;
    esac
done >>log1.log 2>&1
echo "$yn" >>log1.log
```

or put the entire sequence of commands inside parenthes or braces.

```
{ while true; do
    read -p "Are you happy? " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no." >&2;;
    esac
done
echo "$yn"; } >>log1.log 2>&1
```

Like you discovered, and like the term should reveal, a redirection causes the output to go to another place (so a file instead of your terminal, in this case). If you want it displayed on the terminal as well, `tee` does that, but it's probably not suitable for interactive scripts (because you can't include standard *input* in the output).

```
tripleee$ cat >nst
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  read -p "Are you happy? " yn
  case $yn in
    [Yy]*) break;;
    [Nn]*) exit;;
    *) echo "Please answer yes or no." >&2;;
  esac
done
echo "$yn"
^D

tripleee$ chmod +x ./nst

tripleee$ ./nst 2>&1 | tee log1.log
Are you happy? forget it
Please answer yes or no.
Are you happy? no

tripleee$ cat log1.log
Are you happy? Please answer yes or no.
Are you happy? tripleee$
```

Perhaps you are actually looking for the `script` command?

```
tripleee$ script typescript ./nst
Script started, output file is typescript
Are you happy? forget it
Please answer yes or no.
Are you happy? yes ma'am
yes ma'am

Script done, output file is typescript

tripleee$ nl -ba typescript
     1  Script started on Thu Oct 26 20:34:04 2017
     2  command: ./nst
     3  Are you happy? forget it
     4  Please answer yes or no.
     5  Are you happy? yes ma'am
     6  yes ma'am
     7  
     8  Script done on Thu Oct 26 20:34:11 2017
```

Note that the `typescript` file will contain any edits done by the user, i.e. typos and their correction will be included, with the various display codes used by the terminal to execute the edits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and yes I am looking for the question to be displayed on the terminal as well. When I use tee, it does not recognize my "yes" or "no" answer. Keeps saying "Please answer yes or no". I tried to use script but it was just all over the place, perhaps I did not use it right

Comment: The only way I found is to echo "Are you happy? $yn" >>log1.log 2>&1 The problem with this is that I have several prompts with long statements, I like to keep my scripts nice and short

Comment: Added an example with `script`.

Comment: The redirect can be done at an outer scope so your individual `read` prompts don't need an explicit redirect on each, like I show in my very first example.